# QGraphicsItem setTransformOriginPoint seems to be ignored

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qgraphicsitem

I want to transform a `QGraphicsItem` by its `Qt::YAxis`, what works very well.

```
QTransform trans;
trans.rotate (value, Qt::YAxis);
item->setTransformOriginPoint (0,0);
//item->setTransformOriginPoint (500, 250);
item->setTransform (trans);
```

The problem i have is that the `setTransformOriginPoint` seems to be ignored 'cause it dont work. Everytime my item transforms at its left-side. But i want to transform it by its right-side and i think i am affected by this bug:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13378?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Can someone confirm a similar problem like this?

Or what i can do to transform my item at its right-side?

Edit: Sorry i forgot to say that i not use an animation like described at this bug-report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QTransform` has everything about the transformation, include the origins where you want the transform to happen. `setTransformOriginPoint()` only affect simple functions like `rotate()` that does not specify the origins.

Try adding translate to your QTransform before adding rotate().

```
QTransform trans;
trans.translate(500, 250).rotate(value, Qt::YAxis);
item->setTransform(trans);
```

**Edit:**

Yes, `QTransform` in `QGraphicsItem` is not very straightforward to use. It's also really limited on what you can do. Starting with Qt 4.6, [`QGraphicsTransform`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstransform.html) can be used for higher level of control on the transformation. That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: ThanXx for your hint but this just "moves" my item. It still transform / rotates my item on its left-side.

Comment: You are correct. QTransform is always applied to the item origin. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Ok yes, i did it with QGraphicsRotation so cause this class also provides axis to rotate. Thank you!